# Как подключить адаптивные иконки?

Tags: android

С помощью **Image Asset**, встроенном в **Android Studio**, успешно создал иконки с файлами сопровождения, такие как `ic_launcher.xml`, `ic_launcher_round.xml`.

Как их подключить к проекту?

P.S. `SdkVersion 26` - подключен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иконки `ic_launcher.xml, ic_launcher_round.xml` должны храниться в папке `mipmap-anydpi-v26` по пути **...\app\src\main\res**.

Подключаются классически в `manifest`'e.

```
<application
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ...>
```

**Но вы должны знать, что адаптивные иконки работают только для API 26 и выше**.

---

На случай, если API ниже 26 - будут использоваться обычные иконки, такие как `ic_launcher.png, ic_launcher_round.png` , которые находятся в папке `mipmap-hdpi, ... , mipmap-xxxhdpi`.

---

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо! А какие иконки будут показываться на устройствах с API ниже 26?

Comment: @YuriK был рад помочь :) ответ дополнен.

Comment: Очень благодарен! )